# How to order the default column from 1 to n?

Tags: r

silly problem (but could not find a solution online): I want to order the default column from one to N.

This is the dataframe I am working on:

```
                    Ngrams Counts   Lambda         Z
5558              willem f    121 17.97538 11.583211
8095            inter alia     15 17.52591  8.693128
8122 PRESS conferencemario     14 17.45922  8.655312
8325            boca raton     10 17.13645  8.468008
8524            dei paschi      7 16.79998  8.263397
```

As you can see the default column has no order (5558, 8095, 8122, etc.). So, I'd like to order it from 1 to N.

I've already tried with no results to use **factor** and **stulevel**.

How can I sort this out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you call it a "default column"? How are those numbers defaults? Is it even a column in your dataframe? Looks more like row names.

Comment: 1) Those are `rownames`, like @JohnColeman said and in your example they do have an order, an increasing order. 2) What is **stulevel**? It's the first time I have seen it written.

Comment: Thanks. I was wrong in considering it like `column 0`. I found **stulevel** in a discussion here on stackoverflow. But it was not very useful. It is from the package **eeptools**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to re-order the rows by row names, you can extract them with `rownames`, convert it to numeric and then `order`

```
df[order(as.integer(rownames(df))), ]
```

Or if you just want to rename them from `1:N` instead of current names

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```